# ¿ Cómo imprimir una frase al azar?

Tags: c, if

Tengo este código de como calcular la edad:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
char seguir;
int edad, limite=150;


do{
printf("Introduce tu ano de nacimiento: ");
scanf("%d", &edad);

if(limite<edad){

    printf("No seas mentiroso, no puedes tener mas de 150 anos ;)");
}
else{
edad=2017-edad;
printf("Tu edad es: %d", edad);
}


printf("\n¿Desea calcular otra edad? (s/n)?: " );
fflush( stdin );
scanf("%c", &seguir);
} while ( seguir != 'n' );

return 0;
}
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo imprimir una frase diferente en la linea de `printf` dentro del `if`, si se puede imprimir una frase diferente al azar, por ejemplo escribir 3 frases diferentes y que el programa imprima una de esas 3 frases en el `printf` dentro del `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algunas partes de su código no quedan claras , recibe el año de nacimiento y almacena en `edad`, y luego pregunta si es mayor a `150` , así que si ingresará `1990` debería pasar al `else` pero seguro no lo hará. Entonces como alternativa cree otra variable `anio` y cambié las comprobaciones.

Si es posible , podría emplear `arrays` para almacenar los mensajes que desea mostrar y con la función [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) se puede elegir al azar que mensaje mostrar, pero hay un inconveniente con esta función es que generará los mismos valores siempre, teniendo en cuenta esto es que se emplea [srand()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) para evitar números "aleatorios" repetidos empleando la hora del sistema como parámetro `srand (time(NULL))`.

En la parte de las opciones `S/N` `scanf("%c", &seguir);` no espera si no que salta esto es debido a la tecla `ENTER` *(salto de linea , aún está en el buffer)* para solucionar bastaría con añadir un espacio al inicio

```
scanf(" %c", &seguir);
       ^
```

Código Final  <kbd>[Demo Online](https://repl.it/MSOZ)</kbd>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
  int main(){

    srand (time(NULL));
    char seguir;
    int edad,anio, limite=150;
    const char *mensajes[3];
    mensajes[0] = "No seas mentiroso, no puedes tener mas de 150 anos ;)";
    mensajes[1] = "Equivocado, no puedes tener mas de 150 anos ;)";
    mensajes[2] = "Imposible, no puedes tener mas de 150 anos ;)";

    do{
      printf("Introduce tu ano de nacimiento: ");
      scanf("%d", &anio);

      if(limite<(2017-anio)){
          printf(mensajes[(rand() % 3)]);
      }
      else{
        edad=2017-anio;
        printf("Tu edad es: %d", edad);
      }

      printf("\n¿Desea calcular otra edad? (s/n)?: " );
      fflush( stdin );
      scanf(" %c", &seguir);
    } while ( seguir != 'n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Algo asi estaba esperando, apenas soy nuevo

Comment: Para que es el const en el char?

Comment: Porque se asume que los mensajes **no cambiaran** es decir ya estarán definidos. Recomiendo leer e investigar sobre por qué y cuando usar `const`